# what does "I shall not want" mean?

Tags: verbs, old-english

Consider this part of bible : `23 The Lord is my shepherd; I shall not want.`
I was wondering the meaning of second sentence, `I shall not want`.
This is not clear to me the reference to the verb `want` and also the general meaning of the sentence.

Comment: What do you find in the Merriam-Webster definitions for the intransitive usages of _want_?

Comment: I have no idea what `intransitive usage` of a verb is.

Comment: @lonesome, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intransitive_verb

Comment: A good place to start is a Bible dictionary or concordance. For example: http://www.biblestudytools.com/dictionaries/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Want" is a synonym of "lack."  Saying "I shall not want" is similar to saying "I shall not lack" or "I shall not be in need" or "I shall not be lacking anything."

Comment: Hello, Solocutor. As it stands, this question is not suitable for ELU. Giving an answer is sending out the wrong message about what constitutes a suitable question.

Comment: I apologize.  Is it a matter of question phrasing, insufficient research, or something else?

Comment: No research shown, and a basic question easily answered by looking in [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/want): 
**want** (intransitive): 1  to be needy or destitute (although I've heard a Christian speaker select the M-W sense 2 here: have or feel need <never wants for friends> [ I'll not be troubled by cravings]).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth sorry that I am not a native speakers. Even knowing the meaning of want in its intransitive form, still hard for me to know the meaning of `i shall not need`. So that is why I made this question. Well, thank you for explanation anyway.

Comment: @lonesome ELU is intended for linguists and proficient anglophones, as is explained in the Help Center. The sister site ELL is intended for more basic questions. And there are many other sites aimed at helping learners.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically for Biblical text, you could consider looking at one of the many alternative English translations of the same verse, such as you can easily find online at, for example, [Bible Gateway](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=psalm%2023&version=NLT).  Here are two alternative translations that may make more sense to you:

> I lack nothing. (New International Version)
>
> I have all that I need.  (New Living Translation)

Comment: You should know better than to answer this by now.

Comment: Also, these versions select the alternative possibility. The original may equally be translated 'I lack nothing' or 'I will lack nothing'. But this is way off topic.